# adding vc to restricted write18 list

Tags: revision-control, shell-escape

I want to use the [vc bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc/) to add version information to my files. I'd like to go the "write18" route, rather than the makefile route, for now at least. I believe to make it work, I need to allow the vc script to run. TeXlive has a restricted write18 list, of commands that can be run. (I believe I've understood this correctly...) So my question is: how do I the `vc` script to this list?

I'm on ubuntu 10.10 with the packaged version of TeXlive 2009. I think I found the right file, in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf` but it is write only. So before I `sudo emacs` it, I wanted to check I am doing the right thing. Is there a way I could keep my configuration files I've changed in my `~/texmf` tree?

I could just emacs-fu my way to automatically have vc run, but I'd rather have a write18 solution...

So here's the relevant part of my preamble:

```
\immediate\write18{sh ./vc}
\input{vc}
```

I have tried adding `vc` to the `shell_escape_commands` list in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf` but this didn't work. `kpsewhich -expand-var '$shell_escape_commands'` still doesn't list it. So I add `vc` directly into `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` but this doesn't work either. I don't think I can add `sh ./vc` to the shell escape list, since I'm not allowed spaces in that list right? Would adding `sh` to the list work? Is that a good idea? I'm pretty sure that would be dangerous...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the vc bundle.  Looks very useful.  I had been using svninfo but it puts stuff on the page by default.

Comment: Yeah I like it. I've just been doing `M-!` then `sh ./vc` in emacs, which is not ideal. But it's a neat, simple appraoch...

Comment: Adding sh would be a very bad idea.

Comment: I thought so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX Live 2009 had a restricted write18, but it was apparently not safe and so disabled by default. It is enabled in TeX Live 2010.

I cannot help with Ubuntu's packed version specifically because I always install TeX Live myself. Using TeX Live installed by the standard install script, the file that should be changed is `.../texlive/2010/texmf.cnf`. You would add it to the `shell_escape_commands` list.

I'm not a kpathsea expert, so I'm not sure if there's a way to just add to the list without overriding. The obvious thing to try

```
shell_escape_commands = ./vc, ${shell_escape_commands}
```

does not work:

```
$ kpsewhich -expand-var '$shell_escape_commands'
warning: kpathsea: variable `shell_escape_commands' references itself (eventually).
```

But you can just duplicate the original list and then add in `./vc`.

Comment: In the ubuntu version of tl09 it seems to be enabled: `shell_escape=p`. I've updated my question. Maybe I'm trying to add the wrong thing to the list?

Comment: @Seamus: What happens if you add `./vc` to the list?

Comment: It doesn't work. Also if I open a terminal in emacs and type `./vc` I get `Permission Denied`. I need to type `sh ./vc` in the terminal... I'm beginning to think this might not be a LaTeX question?

Comment: @Seamus: Sounds like you need to change the mode on vc. Namely, `chmod +x vc`.

Comment: I've done this, but it doesn't seem to have worked. There isn't even a line in the log about running `vc` ...

Comment: You're running it as `\immediate\write18{./vc}`, right? (Actually, I don't recall if the `\immediate` is needed or not.)

Comment: @TH I've accepted your solution. Thanks for the help! I added `vc` and `./vc` to the relevant list, and changed the write18 command to `./vc` (instead of `sh ./vc`) and now it works.

Comment: For the record, what needs doing is adding `./vc` to the `texmf.cnf` file, and adding permissions as suggested in an earlier comment. then the line in the tex file: `\immediate\write18{./vc}`

Comment: FWIW I did the same thing in TL 2010.  I didn't need to edit `texmf.cnf`